# will iOS 11 support an app which is both 64bit and 32 bit compatible?

Tags: ios, ios11

Our apps are both 32 bit and 64 bit compatible. With iOS 11 being released will my app run fine on 64 bit devices as iOS 11 does not support 32 bit apps.

What is the best suggestion, to remove 32 bit support and just have 64 bit to avoid any issues on iOS 11 or to have both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app support both 64 bits and 32bis it will work on ios 11, if you want to change support to only 64 bits there is the link: [apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your app will work fine on iOS 11 as long as the binary has a 64-bit slice. The change that is occurring in iOS 11 affects binaries which only have 32-bit slices only. Your app will continue to work just fine, assuming you don't try to use iOS 11 APIs (which might cause linker issues — not sure if they're stubbed out — but if you're doing that, you should probably be targeting iOS 11 anyway).

Comment: What if I do use iOS 11 SDK? In that case, I should support 64bit only?

Answer (score -1):

As @Aehmlo says.The change that is occurring in iOS 11 affects binaries which only have 32-bit slices only. Your app will continue to work just fine.

Apple has tweaked the wording of that warning to note that 32-bit apps,So 
 iOS 11 could be the first software update to support 64-bit apps only

Hence, it won't support iPhone 5/ 5c or earlier iPhones.If you will try to install app in iOS 11 then you will notify something like

> App will not work with future versions of iOS. The Developer of this app
>   need to update it to improve it's compatibility.

[image]