# Apple, iOS and 32+64 bit apps built with Visual Studio

Tags: 32bit-64bit, ios11, visual-studio-mac

With the release of the iOS 11 SDK, Visual Studio Mac got rid of the option to compile for previous 32 bit devices (iPhone 5, iPhone 5C and prior).

We're building an application for a client, and one of the main requirements were to support older models (technically, we have to support devices up to iOS 9). But with the release of the iOS 11 SDK, this makes things hard.

For now the solution is to use the 10.3 SDK, which means we can't target (and use) the latest OS and its features. Of course the 64 bit part of the app will run on iOS 11, but I can't find any information about its deprecation.

Is there a fixed date, or even a time range of when will be the 10.3 SDK deprecated and support in the App Store dropped? Since the 32 bit only apps were already removed, I expect that soon developers won't be able to upload 32+64 bit builds either, and apps must target iOS 11.

Comment: Your first paragraph is untrue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652266/will-ios-11-support-an-app-which-is-both-64bit-and-32-bit-compatible

Comment: @rmaddy Well tell that to Visual Studio For Mac - the only option I have there is ARM64, and all the built apps won't install on an iPhone 5. Targeting 10.3 instead of 11 will give me the old options (ARMv7, ARMv7s and ARM64 in various combinations). And as explained by some on the issue you linked, they are noticing the same behaviour, namely the 32-bit slice compile option is completely missing if targeting iOS 11.

Comment: I can't speak about Visual Studio but in my apps built with Xcode I support iOS 8 through iOS 11 and I have no problem supporting both 32 and 64-bit. My Base SDK is iOS 11 and my Deployment Target is iOS 8.1. If Visual Studio doesn't let you support 32-bit when the Deployment Target is set to something earlier than iOS 11 then file a bug report.

Comment: Run at it again. As I explained, I wanted to use iOS 11 as a target - and with it selected, Visual Studio for Mac (and Visual Studio) will only allow ARM64 targeting. With an earlier target, I can do 32 bit ARM, but I won't be able to use iOS 11 APIs. However my question is not about this, but about the support for apps targeting iOS 10.3 or earlier.

Comment: Please reread my comment. The Base SDK defines the latest APIs you can use (iOS 11 in this case). That's what you want. That's what anyone using Xcode 9 uses. Then there is the Deployment Target. This defines the oldest version of iOS you want to support. iOS 10.3 for you. iOS 8.1 for my apps. I have no idea what the Visual Studio way of setting the Deployment Target is. But if Visual Studio doesn't let you support iOS 10.3 (Deployment Target) through iOS 11 (Base SDK) as well as supporting both 32 and 64-bit with such a setup, then the tool is broken and a bug report needs to be filed.

Comment: Okay, that was a bit of a mixup. Coming from Android development, the deployment target had a different meaning for me - in Android terminology the target SDK is what you want to use, i.e. which features are available, while the minimum SDK defines what is apparently the Deployment Target is in iOS.

Comment: Based on the comments, I've edited the question and title to make it clear that this is a *Visual Studio* limitation. (Though it won't be surprising if it becomes impossible in next Xcode version as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio Mac, to target an older OS, set "Deployment Target" to the *minimum* version you wish to support.  For example, use *9.3* to include support for iPhone 4s (that has OS up-to-date). See [wiki iOS devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#iPhone), scroll down to table of discontinued devices.

Details:

- Double-click `info.plist` in Soluion Explorer.
- Set "Deployment Target"  dropdown to the desired OS version.

---

For anyone who comes here wondering how to support both old and new iOS versions, and/or devices with different features:
Use run-time tests to determine whether you are on a device that supports a given feature or iOS version.

> Ray Wenderlich has an older discussion of [checking for feature support](https://www.raywenderlich.com/42591/supporting-multiple-ios-versions-and-devices).